# Using HTML5 Notification API with NWJS - Only icon is clickable on windows chromiuem

Tags: notifications, chromium, nwjs

I have a messaging desktop app, written in Angular and wrapped with NWJS.
The end user gets HTML5 notification when the application is in the background.

On mac everything works fine, but on windows, only the icon is clickable. If the user click on the title or body, nothing happens.

```
var options = {
    dir: 'ltr',
    body: 'Body Text',
    icon: 'assets/images/desktop_notification.png'
}
var title = 'Title'

var notification = new Notification(title, options)
var notification.onclick = function() {
  console.log('click event') // On windows, this will only fire if clicking on the icon
  desktopNotificationOnClickEvent(title, body, chatID)
      $timeout(
        function()
          notification.close()
      , 7000
      )
}
```

How can i fix it so every place on the notification is clickable?

Comment: Which version of Windows - I can't check right now, but I have a Windows 8 box at home, somewhere.

Comment: Win 7/10. On my parallels machine everything works but not on a real windows machine installation

Comment: My silly Win8 machine has an issue and won't boot up. Haven't used it in ages, I'm looking for my DVD so I can reinstall the thing.